# Optimize gesture prediction in GestureOverlayView

Tags: android, gesture

I have generated gestures file via GestureBuilder in emulator.  My concern is sometimes it shows wrong prediction. For e.g. if i have a gesture as capital H then also if i do just a horizontal stroke it detects the match.
I added condition of prediction.score > 1 then also its showing the same.

Is there anything more to be added in java side. I also tried giving SEQUENCE_SENSITIVE and ORIENTATION_INVARIANT. Also tried with setting setOrientationStyle(8);

Please suggest is there any thing more to be added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a minimum score that works for you. I suggest printing out all of the predicted gestures with the name of the gesture and its score. The predicter should automatically organize them in descending score, if you're using the same demo code that I am.

```
for (Prediction prediction : predictions)
    System.out.println(prediction.name + " " + prediction.score);
```

Draw a symbol and look at the what the console spits out. You'll see that it lists every gesture and how close it was to each. Set a minimum score ( if (prediction.score > 3.0) ) and then only call the first in the list of predicted gestures. Tweak that score number until you're happy. I found 10 works well, but for my game that I'm forcing drawing accuracy, I went all the way up to 25.

Just remember that this score is how close it is to the gesture in your gesture file, so if the gesture in the file was drawn poorly, a perfect drawing won't necessarily give the highest score.

EDIT: I also have added a left gesture and a right gesture to my app to prevent false positives. If left and right swipes are ruining your app, I suggest adding these gestures to catch them.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify.